# CSS Slider Using `transform: translateX` To Cycle Through Images

Tags: css, slider, css-animations, transform, translate

Is it possible to have a CSS slider cycle through two images when animating them with the `translateX` transform property?

I'm facing a couple of issues:

1. I can't seem to get the second image to show even though it is in the HTML unless I use `position: absolute` and then the `overflow: hidden` doesn't work on the parent?
2. How do I reset the first image to go back to the beginning to start it all again?

**Note:** in the animation shorthand, the animation lasts for 2.5s and there is an initial delay of 3s.

I only want to do with this with the `translateX` property because I want the 60FPS smoothness (it will be done with `translate3d` when completed, but to make the code easier to read I've used translateX). I don't wish to animate `margin: left` or the `left` property etc.

Any help would be amazing.

Code is below or link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/anna_paul/pen/ZEJrvRp

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 333px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  display: block;
}

.hero-image-1 {
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation: slide-out-image-1 2.5s 3s cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.12, 0.44, 1)
    forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-out-image-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.hero-image-2 {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: slide-in-image-2 2.5s 3s cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.12, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in-image-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <picture>
      <img class="image hero-image-1" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1l7cTX35wqd-4eYvFL8A5QLZ7LbOF9m4J">
    </picture>
    <picture>
      <img class="image hero-image-2" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1iB9R1aoeYSmkPX9Ju3NNOZhKylOjCA0y">
    </picture>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a slider loop you need to define animation points,  when slider moving and stopping. In you case it look that

---

**2.5s + 3s +2.5s +3s = 11s** or **move + pause(out of container) + move + pause = totall**.

---

For the first image we need to animate out of container, then move to start position (out of container), waiting (second image animate), then animate to initial positio and pause.

For the second image, we just show and then hide.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: hsl(201, 27%, 10%);
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

:root {
  --animate: 2.5s;
  --pause: 3s;
  --totall-duration: calc(var(--animate) * 2 + var(--pause) * 2);
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 333px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  width: 200%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-image-1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: slide-out-image-1 var(--totall-duration) 3s
    cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.12, 0.44, 1) infinite;
}
/* start + pause + start + pause = totall */
/* 2.5s + 3s + 2.5s + 3s = 11s*/
@keyframes slide-out-image-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  25.0001% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

.hero-image-2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: slide-in-image-2 var(--totall-duration) 3s
    cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.12, 0.44, 1) infinite;
}

/* start + pause + start + pause = totall */
/* 2.5s + 3s + 2.5s + 3s = 11s*/
@keyframes slide-in-image-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <picture class="hero-image-1">
      <img class="image" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1l7cTX35wqd-4eYvFL8A5QLZ7LbOF9m4J" />
    </picture>
    <picture class="hero-image-2">
      <img class="image" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1iB9R1aoeYSmkPX9Ju3NNOZhKylOjCA0y" />
    </picture>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do slider using `background` property.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { background-color: wheat; }
      h1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: tomato;
      }
      .slider {
        width: 60vw;
        margin: 0 auto;
        aspect-ratio: 485/323;

        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1l7cTX35wqd-4eYvFL8A5QLZ7LbOF9m4J"),
          url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1iB9R1aoeYSmkPX9Ju3NNOZhKylOjCA0y");
        background-attachment: scroll, scroll;
        background-position: 0% 50%, 100% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%, 100%;

        animation: slide-background 11s cubic-bezier(0.50, 0.0, 0.50, 1) 3s infinite;
      }
      @keyframes slide-background {
        0% { background-position: 0% 50%, 60vw 50%; }
        25% { background-position: -60vw 50%, 0% 50%; }
        25.01% { background-position: 60vw 50%, 0% 50%; }
        50% { background-position: 60vw 50%, 0% 50%; }
        75% { background-position: 0% 50%, -60vw 50%; }
        100% { background-position: 0% 50%, 60vw 50%; }
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="slider"><h1>Cars!</h1></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It resizes if you change browser size.

I know you want to use `translate` for performance.
Don't know how much the `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` trick works on animating `background-*` properties here. Does it get same hardware acceleration?

Comment: Yes it does. Also I can't use the background property I do need to use the `<img/>` element.

Answer (score 0):

No, without `position:absolute` its not possible.

For the Position Reset you can use Javascript. Here's a example;

```
var counter = 1;
setInterval(function()
{
  document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked=true;
  counter++;
  if(counter>4){
    counter=1;
  }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the `.container` a `position:relative` to make overflow take effect. Absolutely positioned element require it's container to be [a positioned element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#types_of_positioning).

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 333px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
}

.hero-image-1 {
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation: slide-out-image-1 2.5s 3s cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.12, 0.44, 1)
    forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-out-image-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.hero-image-2 {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: slide-in-image-2 2.5s 3s cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.12, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in-image-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <picture>
      <img class="image hero-image-1" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1l7cTX35wqd-4eYvFL8A5QLZ7LbOF9m4J">
    </picture>
    <picture>
      <img class="image hero-image-2" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1iB9R1aoeYSmkPX9Ju3NNOZhKylOjCA0y">
    </picture>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create a scalable CSS only carousel. It is based on Christian Schaefer's idea of using scroll snap with shift.
Following is 5 slide carousel. In order to make it work you need to ensure:

- You put copy of first `.carousel-slide` element at the end of the list.
- set variables:

  - --no-slides: 6;  //including duplicated first slide  = 5+1
  - --slide-time: 4s; // stay time 75% + slide time 25%
- modify the `tostart` keyframe rule to set times as per corresponding calculations.

```css
     /* variables */
      :root {
        --no-slides: 6;  /* including duplicated first slide */
        --slide-time: 4s; /* stay time 75% + transition time 25% */
      }


      /* document styles */
      body {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;
        scrollbar-width: 0px;
      }

      *::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0;
      }

      *::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: transparent;
      }

      *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
      }

      * {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
      }

      
      /* carousel styles */
      .carousel {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 75%;
        perspective: 100px;
      }

      .carousel-viewport {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
      }

      .carousel-viewport,
      .carousel-slide {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .carousel-slide {
        position: relative;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg,#ff4e50, #f9d423);
      }

      

      .carousel-pusher {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        scroll-snap-align: center;
      }

      /* animations */
      @media (hover: hover) {
        .carousel-pusher {
          animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-name: tonext, snap;
          animation-timing-function: ease;
          animation-duration: var(--slide-time);
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        }

        .carousel-slide:last-child .carousel-pusher {
          animation-name: tostart, snap;
          animation-duration: calc(var(--slide-time) * (var(--no-slides) - 1)), var(--slide-time);
          animation-delay: var(--slide-time), 0s;
        }
      }

      @keyframes tonext {
        0% {
          filter: opacity(0);
        }
        75% {
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
        95% {
          transform: translateX(100%);
        }
        98% {
          transform: translateX(100%);
        }
        99% {
          filter: opacity(1);
          transform: translateX(0%);
        }
      }

      @keyframes snap {
        96% {
          scroll-snap-align: center;
        }
        97% {
          scroll-snap-align: none;
        }
        99% {
          scroll-snap-align: none;
        }
        100% {
          scroll-snap-align: center;
        }
      }

      @keyframes tostart {
        95.8% {     /* some fractions less than next frame time */
          transform: translateX(0%);
        }
        95.823% { /* 0.75 * (100%/--no-slides) + 100% - (100%/--no-slides) +-0.500 adjustment*/
      transform: translateX(calc((var(--no-slides)) * -100%));
    }
    99.5% {  /* 0.99 * (100%/--no-slides) + 100% - (100%/--no-slides)  +-0.500 adjustment*/
      transform: translateX(calc((var(--no-slides) - 2) * -100%));
    }
      }


      /* slide content styles */
      .content {
        padding: 20px ;
        font-size: 150px;
        text-align: center;
      }
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
      <ul class="carousel-viewport">

        <li class="carousel-slide">
          <div class="carousel-pusher"></div>
          <div class="content">1 &#128522;</div>
        </li>

        <li class="carousel-slide">
          <div class="carousel-pusher"></div>
          <div class="content">2 &#128521;</div>
        </li>

        <li class="carousel-slide">
          <div class="carousel-pusher"></div>
          <div class="content">3 &#128516</div>
        </li>

        <li class="carousel-slide">
          <div class="carousel-pusher"></div>
          <div class="content">4 &#128580;</div>
        </li>


        <li class="carousel-slide">
          <div class="carousel-pusher"></div>
          <div class="content">5 &#128526;</div>
        </li>

        <!-- repeat first slide -->
        <li class="carousel-slide">
          <div class="carousel-pusher"></div>
          <div class="content">1 &#128522;</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

To get correct and smooth transitions tinker with `tostart` keyframe change times or add more frames.

**Note:** if animations stop you'll have to set carousel to first slide before starting animations again. There are three animations running in sync.

---

2 slide version

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* variables */
      :root {
        --no-slides: 3; /* including duplicated first slide */
        --slide-time: 4s; /* stay time 75% + transition time 25% */
      }

      /* document styles */
      body {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;
        scrollbar-width: 0px;
      }

      *::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0;
      }

      *::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: transparent;
      }

      *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
      }

      * {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
      }

      /* carousel styles */
      .carousel {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 75%;
        perspective: 100px;
      }

      .carousel-viewport {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
      }

      .carousel-viewport,
      .carousel-slide {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .carousel-slide {
        position: relative;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f995;
      }

      .carousel-slide:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: cadetblue;
      }
      .carousel-pusher {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        scroll-snap-align: center;
      }

      /* animations */
      @media (hover: hover) {
        .carousel-pusher {
          animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-name: tonext, snap;
          animation-timing-function: ease;
          animation-duration: var(--slide-time);
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        }

        .carousel-slide:last-child .carousel-pusher {
          animation-name: tostart, snap;
          animation-duration: calc(var(--slide-time) * (var(--no-slides) - 1)),
            var(--slide-time);
          animation-delay: var(--slide-time), 0s;
        }
      }

      @keyframes tonext {
        0% {
          filter: opacity(0);
        }
        75% {
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
        95% {
          transform: translateX(100%);
        }
        98% {
          transform: translateX(100%);
        }
        99% {
          filter: opacity(1);
          transform: translateX(0%);
        }
      }

      @keyframes snap {
        96% {
          scroll-snap-align: center;
        }
        97% {
          scroll-snap-align: none;
        }
        99% {
          scroll-snap-align: none;
        }
        100% {
          scroll-snap-align: center;
        }
      }

      @keyframes tostart {
        74.999% {
          /* some fractions less than next frame */
          transform: translateX(0%);
        }
        75% {
          /* 0.75 * (100%/--no-slides) + 100% - (100%/--no-slides) */
          transform: translateX(calc((var(--no-slides)) * -100%));
        }
        99.3% {
          /* 0.99 * (100%/--no-slides) + 100% - (100%/--no-slides)  -  <1.0 - 0.0 adjustment>*/
          transform: translateX(calc((var(--no-slides) - 2) * -100%));
        }
      }

      /* slide content styles */
      .content {
        object-fit: fill;
      }
      .image {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: fill;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="carousel">
      <ul class="carousel-viewport">
        <li class="carousel-slide">
          <div class="carousel-pusher"></div>
          <div class="content"
            ><img
              class="image"
              src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1l7cTX35wqd-4eYvFL8A5QLZ7LbOF9m4J"
          /></div>
        </li>

        <li class="carousel-slide">
          <div class="carousel-pusher"></div>
          <div class="content"
            ><img
              class="image"
              src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1iB9R1aoeYSmkPX9Ju3NNOZhKylOjCA0y"
          /></div>
        </li>

        <!-- repeat first slide -->
        <li class="carousel-slide">
          <div class="carousel-pusher"></div>
          <div class="content"
            ><img
              class="image"
              src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1l7cTX35wqd-4eYvFL8A5QLZ7LbOF9m4J"
          /></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```